# I can't find the individual and interpolate options under inset tool

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, faces

[image][image]I am not able to inset multiple faces individually. Pressing <kbd>I</kbd> twice also doesn't work. blender version 2.64a x 64 win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "individual" option in the "inset faces" panel in the bottom left part of the 3D view (the option will be shown after a first inset operation).

[image]

Comment: i don't have those options.I have added  screen captures.

Comment: they will appear in the (t) tool shelf after you pressed "i". Or you can press "f6" after you pressed i and accepted.

Comment: I get the inset options but interpolate and individual options are not present.please see my screen captures.

Comment: @JohnFrancis perhaps a Blender version difference ? I am in 2.77a

Comment: so how can I get blender to do this

Comment: @JohnFrancis Try Alt+E then "individual faces" (if that exists for you) then scale them with individual origins.

Comment: thank-you that works 1. alt+E  2.individual faces 3. right click  4. scale or "s" ..... this gives the same effect but it didn't fix my inset, I need inset so I will be able to do all the above steps with a single step.

Comment: @JohnFrancis You should use the latest version of blender, 2.77a.